# Calculating the factorial of every element in an integer array

Tags: java, arrays, factorial

I need to create a Method that has 2 parameters in Java, upperborder and lowerborder. This method must create an array from the number 2 to the number 10.
Then I must implement another method, that calculates the factorial for a given number.
Then I must implement a third method that calculates the factorial for every element in the created array and test all these methods in a TestClass.

I know how to do this, but apparently I'm making some kind of a mistake in my code and it gives me the StackOverflow exception. I read the code a couple of times, but I can't seem to quite understand where I'm wrong.

```
package fakultaetinarray;


public final class FakultaetinArray{
    private int i;
    private int[] a;
    private int j;

    public FakultaetinArray(){
        System.out.println("Given array : ");
        createArray(1, 9);
        System.out.println("Factorial for every element : ");
        FakinArray();

    }
    public int fakRe(int n){
        if(n == 1){
            return n;
        }
        return n * fakRe(n - 1);
    }
    public void createArray(int untergrenze, int obergrenze){
        this.a = new int[obergrenze];
        for(this.j = 1; j <= a.length; j++){
            a[i] = j + 1;
            System.out.println(a[i]);
        }
    }
    public void FakinArray(){
        a[0] = 2;
       for(i = 1; i < a.length; i++){
          int fak = fakRe(a[i]);
          a[i] = fak;
          System.out.println(fak);

       }

    }

}
```

Comment: This would be a perfect time to try stepping through the code in your debugger to see where the program is not doing what you expected.

Comment: In your case `fakRe(0)` will throw a StackOverflowError exception. You are trying to use values in the array you didn't initialise.

Comment: How does `a[i] = j + 1;` even compile? `i` is not initialized.

Comment: `a[i] = j + 1;`... The value of `i` never changes here

Comment: @Gendarme It's a field, so it's 0

Comment: @cricket_007 Even before the object has been constructed? This is happening inside the constructor.

Comment: @Gendarme Non-final fields are not checked as to whether they have been initialised or not. They have default values instead.

Comment: @Gendarme though to be fair, they should be local variables and not fields in the first place.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The reason you're getting `StackOverflowError`s is due to your recursive method not having a case when `n == 0`.

The *reason* that your values are coming in as `0` is due to how you're constructing your loop.

```
for(this.j = 1; j <= a.length; j++){
    a[i] = j + 1;
    System.out.println(a[i]);
}
```

It's unclear why you're using `j` here at all, and `i` is initialized to its default value of 0, so in all reality, you're only ever filling *one* element of your array with a positive value and all of the others are at zero.

You need to reconsider how your loops are constructed.  I would ***strongly*** encourage you not to make them fields, but declare them as part of the loop construct instead.

Comment: Thanks man, I fixed it. Your encouragement proved to be helpful, but I left the array as a field, because I need to use it in all the other methods.

Comment: @nasdenkov:  I don't have a problem with the array being a field, but the loop variables which I highlighted definitely shouldn't be.

Answer (score 0):

`if(n == 1){` is not a strong enough condition to block the recursion: `n` can go below 1. In your particular case, you have a situation where `n` is 0.

Consider unwinding the recursion to a simple loop in any case. As a rule of thumb, recursion is not good for O(N) stuff.

Comment: Actually recursion is fine because factorial of 13 is too large to fit into an `int` so the range of valid inputs is pretty limited.

Comment: `n` is 0 as `a[i]` is 0.

Comment: So you like the idea of a recursion depth of 13? I don't. Especially if the code is refactored to `long`, or eventually `BigInteger`. Use a `for` loop. Pretty please, with sugar on top.

Comment: A `long` doesn't help much. factorial of 21 is too big.  You have  bigger problems than using recursion. If you are using BigInteger, perhaps it should blow up first. Using a formula to estimate it `O(1)` would be better. btw didn't downvote.

Comment: Of course in c++ we can get the compiler to evaluate it. Nice.

Comment: And do feel free to downvote! It's a crucial part of the peer review process.

Comment: I only downvote bad answers, not ones I have a quibble with ;)

Comment: It is safer programming practice to code the condition as `n <= 1` to catch all cases of 1, 0, and (invalid) negative arguments.

Comment: @Bathsheba, yes, you are right. I created an iterative Method for the calculation of the factorial. Thank you.